# Как закрашивать текст в элементах перемещающимся цветным блоком?

Tags: javascript, css3, css-animation

Есть табы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию цвет текста - серый.
При переключении нужно чтобы красный цвет плавно заменял серый со смещением.
Вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под табом должна быть черточка.
Думается что все красное должно быть одним блоком.
Можно как то сделать так, чтобы по выбору таба, этот красный блок туда-сюда ездил, закрашивая плавно текст со смещением цвета?

Какие-то решения есть с -webkit-background-clip: text; и -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; но результат не получил.
Может кто делал такое, есть рабочие примеры.

Аналог - табы в Твиттере.

Есть вот такой вариант -
Но, при этом не проскроллить табы по горизонтали. Мешается -webkit-background-clip: text; Ну а без него не работает((

```css
.clip-text {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/480/200?random);
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px;
}

span {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="clip-text">
        <span>JINTOS</span>
        <span>22JINTOS</span>
        <span>JINTOS</span>
        <span>22JINTOS</span>
        <span>JINTOS</span>
        <span>22JINTOS</span>
        <span>JINTOS</span>
        <span>22JINTOS</span>
        <span>JINTOS</span>
        <span>22JINTS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: не относится к вопросу: исправьте у себя опечатку: не главнОЕ, а главнАЯ ;-)

Comment: @Sevastopol' Суть не в работе табов, а в перемещении блока с бэкграундом. Он перемещается если менять position, но не в данном примере это не увидеть, так как нельзя проскролить из-за background-clip

Answer (score 2):

Для старта пойдёт, думаю.
Чуть позже может доведу до нормального поведения.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('-hover')) {
    el.style.cssText = `
    --ew: ${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width}px;
    --ex: ${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left - el.getBoundingClientRect().left}px;`;
  }
}, true);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  --ew: 0;
  --ex: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--ew);
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--ex);
  bottom: -1px;
  transition: 
    width .3s linear,
    left .3s linear;
}

.wrapper .clip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-color: #777;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, red);
  background-size: var(--ew) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: var(--ex) center;
  transition: 
    background-position .3s linear,
    background-size .3s linear;
}

.wrapper .clip span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em .25em;
  color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .clip span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clip">
    <span class="-hover">Главная</span>
    <span class="-hover">Портфолио</span>
    <span class="-hover">Ещё что-то</span>
    <span class="-hover">ыыы</span>
    <span class="-hover">JINTOS</span>
    <span class="-hover">22JINTOS</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит хорошо) Спасибо. Но если ограничить wrapper в 300 - 400px, то табы не скроллятся горизонтально опять же(

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите свое решение со смещением маски для текста и отдельно реализуйте плавающую черточку, вроде такой:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  width: calc(15vw - 15px);
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a {
  width: 15vw;
  padding: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

a:nth-child(1):hover ~ .line {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line {
  transform: translateX(15vw);
}

a:nth-child(3):hover ~ .line {
  transform: translateX(30vw);
}

a:nth-child(4):hover ~ .line {
  transform: translateX(45vw);
}

a:nth-child(5):hover ~ .line {
  transform: translateX(60vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
  <a href="">Link 4</a>
  <a href="">Link 5</a>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```